# Tomcat + Jboss encoding error

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, jboss

I have a cluster with different os(windows and gnu/linux) running an app with JBOSS(with javabeans made by my team) and the "front-end" with Tomcat.

Every time that the app is running in a gnu/linux the system broke all the encode(ã,é,õ,á). The chartset of the html is utf-8.

I saw a solution for this using getBytes(utf-8) to convert and force the String to be on utf-8 of the os. But there is a lot of Strings and the code will be "polluted" if i use this for every string.

There is any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because all data coming from the sybase(database) was with wrong encoding. To resolve we added a flag on connection url( CHARSET=iso_1 ).